# PRIIPs Regulation: Adjustments required by curve methodology

Tags: pca, priips

I am currently looking at a structured product whose payoff depends on EURIBOR1Y and the associated requirements for PRIIPs computations. More precisely the regulation says the following:

The simulated rate for each tenor point T, is the current rate at tenor point T:

(a) multiplied by the exponential of the simulated return

(b) adjusted for any shifts used to ensure positive values for all tenor point, and

(c) adjusted so that the expected mean matches current expectations for the rate at tenor point T, at the end of the recommended holding period.

I am fine until (c) but what exactly is meant with (c)? What is the expected mean and what perhaps more importantly what are current expectations of EURIBOR1Y?